# Testcafe adding Prefix to Authorization header

Tags: testcafe

We are using a token sent as uri parameter to our website. But the website makes an xhr request, testcafe is adding prefix:

**:~~~TestCafe added this prefix to control the authorization flow ~~~ TOKEN_XXX**

I believe this prefix shouldn't be added to this request

Node JS version : "v16.13.2"
Test Cafe version : "2.2.0"
Platform : Windows 10
Chrome Version 108

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe uses this prefix when exchanging messages between the client and the TestCafe proxy. When sending a request to your application's server, the prefix is removed.
If a request with such a prefix in the header arrives at the server of your application, this behavior is incorrect. In this case, please create an issue in the [TestCafe repository on GitHub](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new/choose). Please attach an example to the issue that reproduces the behavior you described.